# Show pdf in symfony2

Tags: symfony, pdf, controller, download

I want to show a pdf, but I did this and I only gets to download the pdf: This is my code:

```
        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);
        $response->trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
        $response->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $file . '.pdf');
        return $response;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting Content-Type header?

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

Also, ditch that `setContentDisposition` call since `DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT` value forces your browser to download the file.

Comment: Thanks, using: ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE all works fine. :)